# chillerlan/php-qrcode change QR color

Tags: php, laravel

Hi as per this sample https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode/blob/main/examples/qrcode-interactive.php this will make the qr change color but the update version is not working
I want this M_FINDER_DOT,M_FINDER to work

My code:

```
      $moduleValues = [


            QRMatrix::M_FINDER_DOT     => 'FFD117',
            QRMatrix::M_FINDER         => 'B8FF3E',
    
        ];
        $moduleValues = array_map(function ($v) {
            if (preg_match('/[a-f\d]{6}/i', $v) === 1) {
                return in_array('png', ['png', 'jpg', 'gif'])
                    ? array_map('hexdec', str_split($v, 2))
                    : '#' . $v;
            }
            return null;
        }, $moduleValues);

        

$options = new QROptions([
    'version' => QRCode::VERSION_AUTO,
    'eccLevel' => QRCode::ECC_H,
    'maskPattern'      => 4,
    'addQuietzone'     => false,
    'quietzoneSize'    => -1,
    'scale' => 5,
    'outputType' => QRCode::OUTPUT_IMAGE_PNG,
    'imageBase64' => true,
    'moduleValues'     => $moduleValues,
    'imageTransparent' => false,

]);
```

Output of my code
[image]

When i run the sample which i want
[image]

QRMatrix in sample

```
class QRMatrix{

    /*
     * special values
     */

    /** @var int */
    public const IS_DARK            = 0b100000000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_NULL             = 0b000000000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_LOGO             = 0b001000000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_LOGO_DARK        = 0b101000000000;

    /*
     * light values
     */

    /** @var int */
    public const M_DATA             = 0b000000000010;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER           = 0b000000000100;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_SEPARATOR        = 0b000000001000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_ALIGNMENT        = 0b000000010000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_TIMING           = 0b000000100000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FORMAT           = 0b000001000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_VERSION          = 0b000010000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_QUIETZONE        = 0b000100000000;

    /*
     * dark values
     */

    /** @var int */
    public const M_DARKMODULE       = 0b100000000001;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_DATA_DARK        = 0b100000000010;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER_DARK      = 0b100000000100;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_ALIGNMENT_DARK   = 0b100000010000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_TIMING_DARK      = 0b100000100000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FORMAT_DARK      = 0b100001000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_VERSION_DARK     = 0b100010000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER_DOT       = 0b110000000000;

    /*
     * values used for reversed reflectance
     */

    /** @var int */
    public const M_DARKMODULE_LIGHT = 0b000000000001;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER_DOT_LIGHT = 0b010000000000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_SEPARATOR_DARK   = 0b100000001000;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_QUIETZONE_DARK   = 0b100100000000;
    }
```

QRMatrix  in current version

```
 */
final class QRMatrix{

    /** @var int */
    public const M_NULL       = 0x00;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_DARKMODULE = 0x02;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_DATA       = 0x04;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER     = 0x06;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_SEPARATOR  = 0x08;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_ALIGNMENT  = 0x0a;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_TIMING     = 0x0c;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FORMAT     = 0x0e;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_VERSION    = 0x10;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_QUIETZONE  = 0x12;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_LOGO       = 0x14;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_FINDER_DOT = 0x16;
    /** @var int */
    public const M_TEST       = 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Disregard this question, the link i provided was old version, but there is way to check the new version in github.